# Circular Dependency on Modals in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, modal-dialog

I have a Login Modal with a button to open a register modal, and the register modal has a button to go back to the login modal.
This produces a circular dependency, and I cant figure out how to solve this..

```
public dialog: MatDialog
```

In the login modal:

```
goRegister() {
this.dialog.closeAll();
this.dialog.open(RegisterComponent);
}
```

In the register Modal:

```
goLogin() {
this.dialog.closeAll();
this.dialog.open(LoginComponent);
}
```

Comment: when are you calling `goRegister` and `goLogin`?

Comment: `goRegister` is called in `LoginComponent`, once the user clicks `create Account` and vice versa

Comment: are you getting an error related to circular dependency?

Comment: Yes: _WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
src\app\routes\sessions\register\register.component.ts -> src\app\routes\sessions\login\login.component.ts -> src\app\routes\sessions\register\register.component.ts_

Comment: Hmm, try changing your app in such a way that the login and register components don't depend on themselves, you can emit an event to the parent and use that to open required dialogue in the parent.

Comment: How does this work on a modal? I can emit events in the modal, but how do I listen to them in my parent component if i call the modal with `this.dialog.open(LoginComponent);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as for me, a better way to fix it, move open modal methods to parent component. Use MatDialogRef in your modals to close it with some result. It helps you to pass data to parent component, according to this data you build your next logic. For example:

```
constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<RegisterComponent>){}

close(showLoginModal: boolean): void {
 this.dialogRef.close(showLoginModal)
}
```

And in parent component show modal and subscribe to modal closing.

```
constructor(private dialog: MatDialog){}

openRegisterComponent(): void {
  this.dialog.open(RegisterComponent)
      .afterClosed()
      .subscribe(showLoginModal => showLoginModal && this.openLoginComponent();
}

openLoginComponent(): void {
  this.dialog.open(LoginComponent)
      .afterClosed()
      .subscribe(showRegisterComponent => showRegisterComponent && this.openRegisterComponent();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to always utilize Smart and Dumb concepts with your components. Encapsulate both components in a parent component and communicate both children to the parent with event emitters. When the parent component receive that event, he will do what he wants to do with that (in that case open another modal).